# How to determine code and assets size within a SWF?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way to take a compiled SWF file and figure out how much of it's size is used by code and how much is assets (images, etc)? I'd like to see if I can get my Flex SWF smaller but I'm unsure what's taking up the most space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -link-report MXMLC compiler parameter or you can use the swfdump tool in the open source Flex SDK to see what is in a SWF.